# Password field with numbers only

Tags: html, css, asp.net, firefox, web

I'm creating a web app and i'd like to have a special password field for smart phones.
Users passwords will be only numbers so I want a special keyboard (It's done and it works)
The problem is Firefox for android, the password field is not displayed as password but as simple text.

My ASP.NET field :

```
 <asp:TextBox Type="Number" pattern="[0-9]*" CssClass="PassTxtBox" ID="Txt_psswd" runat="server" Columns="20" MaxLength="20" Width="100%" Height="30px" ForeColor="Black"></asp:TextBox>
```

My CSS :

```
.PassTxtBox{
    -webkit-text-security: circle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change  input type to `Type="Password"`

```
<asp:TextBox Type="Password" pattern="[0-9]*" CssClass="PassTxtBox" ID="Txt_psswd" runat="server" Columns="20" MaxLength="20" Width="100%" Height="30px" ForeColor="Black"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: It does not work, the virtual keyboard of Android shows letters and numbers if I set Type to password.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add  `text-security:circle;` to Class `PassTxtBox`

```
.PassTxtBox{
    -webkit-text-security: circle;
    -moz-text-security:circle;
     text-security:circle;
}
```

Try to  add this

```
 window.onload = function(){
            init(); 
        }
        function init(){
            var test= document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
            var style = window.getComputedStyle(x);

            if(style.webkitTextSecurity){
                //Don't perform any action
            }else{
                test.setAttribute("type","password");
            }
        }
```